# Sorting an array of integers from 0...n, with n digits, in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I'm attempting to create an algorithm that can sort an array of integers in O(N) time.

- The number of digits in all of the intergers is N
- Each element has an unknown number of digits
- The algorithm should sort the array in O(N) time regardless of how the digits are distributed

I have a working solution for this problem, that runs in O(N) time, I'm just having trouble trying to prove that it does so.

```
Create a set of N buckets and add items to their corresponding bucket based off how
many digits are in the integer -O(N)

Radix sort each bucket, and then concatenate the buckets back together. 
Sum k=0 to N of O(k*n)
k = Number of digits
n = number of items with k digits
```

The solution that I have come up with is that the `∑k*∑n` will always equal N.

Attempt at a proof

```
Base case: Array has 1 item.
T(N)= k*1. k=N = O(N)
```

I'm unsure how to do the inductive step (if it is even required).

Comment: Your radix sort idea may be more expensive than you think. Eg. N=4, array = [1,23,456,7890]

Comment: @ElKamina, in your example, with the ending 0 removed, n=9

Answer (score 3):

The following screenshot explains it:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figure it out.